# Sequences data ,state sequence

Tags: r, sequence, state, data-mining, traminer

I have some questions about sequence data or sequence mining. I would like to create a sequence with Traminer in R; my data is longitudinal and I will use state sequences.

This is an example:

```
1980   1981   1982    1983    1984    1985 
study  study  study   work    work    work
single single married married married married
...... .....  ......  ...... .. ....  ......
...... ..... ....... .......  ......  ......
```

My questions are:

1. Which methods in state sequence should I use?
2. If there is more than one, which is the best?

If you have any ideas, tutorials or articles to read I'll be happy; any kind of help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the TraMineR website (http://mephisto.unige.ch/traminer), you should have a look to the following ressources.

- Gabadinho, A., Ritschard, G., Müller, N.S. & Studer, M. (2011), Analyzing and visualizing state sequences in R with TraMineR, Journal of Statistical Software. Vol. 40(4), pp. 1-37. http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i04
- Studer, Matthias (2013). WeightedCluster Library Manual: A practical guide to creating typologies of trajectories in the social sciences with R. LIVES Working Papers, 24. DOI: 10.12682/lives.2296-1658.2013.24. http://mephisto.unige.ch/weightedcluster/WeightedCluster.pdf